# how to call a factory from a regular function in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this factory which is called by some controllers.

```
app.factory('fileData', function($http) { 
    return {
        get:  function(filename){  return $http({ method: 'GET',  url: filename}); 
        }
    };
});
```

Now I want to call it from a regular function and return the data from the factory. How can I do that? This one does not work because the fileData passed in is not recognized without $scope.

```
function getData (file, fileData) {
   rels = [];
   var handleSuccess = function(data, status) {
      rels = data;
      console.log(rels);
   };
   fileData.get(filename).success(handleSuccess);
   return rels;     
}
```

Any idea how to go around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `return rels` inside `handleSuccess`, you're returning before `handleSuccess` is getting called. So you're signaling that the function completed execution prematurely.

```
function getData (file, fileData) {
   rels = [];
   var handleSuccess = function(data, status) {
      rels = data;
      console.log(rels);

      return rels; // Return rels when the Promise is finished
   };

   fileData.get(file).success(handleSuccess);
}
```

Since you're returning the promise from `$http`, you need to handle its execution in an asynchronous way which, is simply not returning until the promise is resolved.

It would also be a good idea to add a `reject` handler.

[Additionally, `.success()` is deprecated and you should use `.then()` and `.catch()` respectively for handling `resolve()` and `reject()` of the Promise appropriately.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)

See below for the preferred approach to Promises with `$http`

```
fileData.get(file)
  .then(handleSuccess)
  .catch(handleFailure); // Handle any errors returned from $http
```

---

**EDIT** Update for DI example for controller

You need to inject the `fileData` factory into your Angular Controller. For more info on Dependency Inject see the [Angular Docs for DI](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). Just to note, DI is a huge piece of Angular so it is pretty fundamental to understand this before proceeding.

```
angular
  .module('yourApp')
  .controller('yourController', ['$scope', 'fileData', function($scope, fileData) {
    // Expose getData via $scope
    $scope.getData = getData;

    function getData(file, fileData) {
      var rels = [];
      var handleSuccess = function(data, status) {
        rels = data;
        console.log(rels);
        return rels;   
      };

      fileData.get(file)
        .then(handleSuccess);
    }
  }]);
```

Comment: ajaegle and peteb, thanks for the explanation which is very helpful to me since I am new to this. The function won't work because fileData passed in is undefined and I don't know how to reference the factory. How can I pass in the reference to the factory into the function?

Comment: @Shawn updated my answer to show how to inject your `fileData` factory into a controller

Comment: Hi, Peteb, so I am back to controller again. My original question was using "regular" function without controller. How can I wait until the promise finished?

Comment: @Shawn are you saying you want to use an angular service outside of angular?

Comment: Be careful: Omiiting the `var` keyword creates a global variable. The rels variable inside the `getData` function would never be accessible from outside when not declared as global. This sample will not work as there is no chance to receive the data from the `getData` method.

Comment: "outside of angular". Yes, sort of. but still in the same page and the same module though.

Comment: After the edit, now with the var keywork, the handler function modifies a local variable when the promise is resolved but the getData method returns undefined. This will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to the method exposed in the factory (`get`) uses the `$http` service which returns a promise. So you cannot get the result of this call in a synchronous way.

In your sample the `return rels` happens way before the handleSuccess method is called and thus you are returning the old value (an empty array).

The reason it works inside of a controller function is that the controller instance is living for a longer time and when the server call returns successfully, the variable in you controller's `$scope` is assigned (which then is reflected in your UI via the angular data binding).

So the best way to solve this, is to avoid having a synchronous api in your "regular function". Could you probably make this also async by returning a promise?